# Hadoop 2.8.1 Sqoop 1.4.6 Import from SQL Server Data Issue ?

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, sqoop

I have been trying to import my tables from SQL server to Hadoop.
I get the error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
which comes due to versions of Sqoop and Hadoop

I am using Hadoop 2.8.1 and Sqoop 1.4.6 on my Ubuntu System.

Can you tell me which dependency jar files that I might be missing or the correct version compatibility ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any sandbox environment from cloudera or hortonworks? If so they will provide the appropriate versions which are compatible with each other.

Comment: This should probably be a comment rather than an answer.